# SSRS Calculate duration between two dates

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

How do I write the follow SSRS Calculation below in SSRS expression

Actual Calculation example below
`=((deldate+deltime) –(orddate+ordtime))*24`

```
deldate     delTime  orddate    ordTime  *24
13/01/2015  14:25   14/01/2015  13:55    23.50
20/01/2015  12:00   20/01/2015  17:02    5.03
```

This worked in SQL Toad but not in SSRS

```
(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(A.DELDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') ||' '|| TO_CHAR(A.DELTIME,'HH24:MI'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') - TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(A.ORDDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') ||' '|| TO_CHAR(A.ORDTIME,'HH24:MI'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'))*24 AS "DiffinHours",
```

Comment: The "SS" in SSRS stands for "SQL Server".  Of course, the tool can connect to other databases, but that is not the typical configuration.  Is your actual database Oracle (as suggested by the code) or SQL Server (as suggested by the tool)?

Comment: Yes, it is an SQL Server

Comment: What is the data type of each field. Also which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: Data Type = DATE for all 4 fields deldate, deltime, orddate & ordtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `TO_CHAR`s to `Format`, `TO_DATE`s to `CDate`, and use a `DateDiff` instead of subtracting.  To get hours in decimals, find the difference in minutes and divide by 60.0:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, 
          CDate(Format(Fields!deldate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & " " & Format(Fields!deltime.Value, "HH:mm")), 
          CDate(Format(Fields!orddate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & " " & Format(Fields!ordtime.Value, "HH:mm"))
         ) / 60.0
```

Comment: I'm getting a run time error in expression - conversion from string "29/01/2015 14:00" to type 'Date' is not valid.

Comment: I took a guess based on the above date formatting that your system/report settings needed to be in dd/mm/yy format.  If these settings are actually en-US, you'll need mm/dd/yy; updated my answer.

Comment: same problem - [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression]  contains an error: Conversion from string "00/03/2015 21:45" to type 'Date' is not valid.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at the data from your source query there; I'm not sure how a field of type date could be created without a month.

Comment: Ok - this seems to be partially working however, why do I get  #error on some results and some weird number format if over 2 or 4 days?

Comment: Again, I'd double check the raw data from your source query specifically the data types.  All the expression does is append the date and time parts of two `DATETIME` fields.  You could also try adding extra columns to specifically check that the output of each `CDate` is what you expect.

Comment: This is ok now - Just had to change the date format to 'dd/mmm/yyyy' Thanks for your help stubaker.

Comment: Hi stubake- I have another question how do I add an IFF conditional format to the above i.e. IFF greater than 48 flag "Red" else "white"

Comment: If you're looking to change the text color, go to Text Box Properties > Font > and click Fx next to Color to set an expression like `=IIF(Fields!myfield.Value > 48, "Red", "White")`

Comment: It doesn't like Fields!myfield.value not sure why

Comment: You would need to replace `myfield` with your field name.  Or you could also use `Me.Value`: `=IIF(Me.Value > 48, "Red", "White")`

Comment: This does not work with numeric  expression values in SSRS 2008

Comment: Another option is `=ReportItems!textbox1.Value` where textbox1 is the name of your textbox